# Failed to pull container image registry.eu-de.bluemix.net

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, serverless, ibm-cloud-functions, container-registry

Here's what I have:

- a java application (as `JAR` file)
- docker image (built from `Dockerfile`) with this java application

The image was built with:
`sudo docker build -t registry.eu-de.bluemix.net/watson2018/imagerecognition:latest .`

The image is pushed to a private docker registry in IBM Cloud

```
$ ibmcloud cr image-list
Listing images...

REPOSITORY                                               TAG      DIGEST         NAMESPACE    CREATED       SIZE     SECURITY STATUS   
registry.eu-de.bluemix.net/watson2018/imagerecognition   latest   aba50d315338   watson2018   2 hours ago   194 MB   Scanning...
```

I can see the image in the private registry https://console.bluemix.net/containers-kubernetes/registry/private and I can pull it.

Then in the same location (Germany) I created successfully an **IBM Function**: `bx wsk action create recognize --docker registry.eu-de.bluemix.net/watson2018/imagerecognition:latest`

The problem is:
When I run the function, it can't pull the image.

```
Results:
{
   "error": "Failed to pull container image 'registry.eu-de.bluemix.net/watson2018/imagerecognition:latest'."
}
```

Any idea how to run this function with docker image from the private registry?

Comment: Same account? Authorization done? Images are protected and need authorization.

Comment: Same account. How to provide authorization? Some more params in Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Actions only support public registries like an image publicly available on dockerhub.

Comment: Oh. Sad to hear that. Would it make perfectly sense to have docker images for IBM Functions stored in the IBM Cloud? I feel disapointed...